# How to fetch data from Instagram api with Axios and Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, instagram

I want to make an api call with Instagram api using Axios/Reactjs i get already data but i am having rendering issue.I don't know where i make mistake but i cant render the caption or image from instagram post.thanks for help.

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import '../styles/home.css'
import '../App.css';
import axios from 'axios';


const api = axios.create({
    baseURL:`https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_url&access_token=IGQ.....` 
})

    class Home extends Component {

        state={
            courses: []
        }
        constructor(){
            super();
            api.get('/').then(res=>{
                console.log(res.data)
                this.setState({courses: res.data})
            })
    
        }
        createCourse = async()=> {
            let res = await api.post('/', {title:"Test", id:4 ,autor:'Test'})
            console.log(res);
        }
   

        render() {
          return
          <div>
              {this.state.courses.map(course => <h2 key={course.id}>{course.caption}</h2> )}
            <h1>Hello</h1>
           </div>
        }
      }
      export default Home;
  
  


//
```

Comment: "i am having rendering issue" Could you please elaborate? These generic "error descriptions" are really not helpful. Imagine a user of your app coming to you just with "it's broken" and no further info.

Comment: yes you are right. i get the data from api as array with console.log(res.data) but i am having the problem with render.if i write a state of caption from array as h2 its not showing anything error  thats way i cant write the spesific error. i just want to if its good way to try render api json array like how i did or is there any better way to render

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch data in componentDidMount method.

```
componentDidMount() {
  api.get('/').then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
    this.setState({courses: res.data})
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to display the data before the fetch was completed.

Change your `<div>` from this:

```
<div>
    {this.state.courses.map(course => <h2 key={course.id}>{course.caption} 
    </h2>)}
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div>
    {this.state.courses && this.state.courses.map(course => <h2 key={course.id}>{course.caption} 
    </h2>)}
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

So it only renders when data isn't null.

-This is happening due to fetching before mounting, so in order to fix that, implement the componentDidMount() method.